# HAProxy: If I bind to ports 32768-65535, the computer lose access to other servers

Tags: haproxy

I need to configure a HAProxy frontend like this:

```
frontend web-server
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8

    bind :8080
    bind :32768-65535

    default_backend service
```

But, that configuration don't let me connect to other servers, internal or external.

```
$ wget www.google.com
--2016-12-22 23:21:13--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 172.217.6.196, 2607:f8b0:4006:804::2004
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|172.217.6.196|:80... failed: Cannot assign requested address.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|2607:f8b0:4006:804::2004|:80... failed: Network is unreachable.
```

**If I comment the line `bind :32768_65535` and restart HAProxy, I can connect to other servers again.**

I think I'm making HAProxy binds to ports that are necessary to start a connection, and that's the reason why that configuration is causing this problem.

**How can I configure HAProxy to listen in those ports, without that connection problem?**

**EDIT:**

- HAProxy 1.6
- Ubuntu 16.04 (it's a clean installation)

Comment: Are you sure you need to bind all of those specific ports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, haproxy is binding every local port from 32768 to 65535 inclusive. This is a problem because, by default, outgoing connections bind a local port within this range:

```
# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 32768    60999
```

To resolve the issue you will need to select a local port range that is not otherwise going to be used on your system and reconfigure this sysctl to use it. For example:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range="24576 32767"
```

(And make it persistent in `/etc/sysctl.conf`.)